# Rails Single Table Inheritance - What is the best way to explicitly set type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) in my rails application, and want to explicitly set the type of an instance.

I have the following;

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
class SpecialEvent < Event
```

which is implemented through single table inheritance.

`SpecialEvent.new` works as expected, but I want to be able to do things like

```
Event.new(:type => 'SpecialEvent')
```

So I can create different sub_types easily in the application.

However this doesn't work and seems to set `:type` to `nil`, not the value I set it to; I suspect this is because by calling `Event.new` it is overwriting the `:type` argument.

Has anyone got a good way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create sub-types on the fly ?

Comment: No, I want to create instances of sub-types, where I want to programmatically determine which sub_type they are

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're trying to dynamically instantiate a subtype, and you have the type as a string, you can do this:

```
'SpecialEvent'.constantize.new()
```

Comment: Just a quick note here - make sure you're sanitizing input if this string is coming from a form post or similar - you don't want to call #constantize on arbitrary data from a possibly malicious source, eg `klass.constantize.new() if valid_class_names.include?(klass)`

Answer (score 14):

from "Pragmatic - Agile Web Development with rails 3rd edition", page 380

> There’s also a less obvious constraint (with STI). The attribute type
>   is also the name of a built-in Ruby method, so accessing it directly
>   to set or change the type of a row may result in strange Ruby
>   messages. Instead, access it implicitly by creating objects of the
>   appropriate class, or access it via the model object’s indexing
>   interface, using something such as this:
>
> person[:type] = 'Manager'

man, this book really rocks

Answer (score 5):

> No, I want to create instances of
>   sub-types, where I want to
>   programmatically determine which
>   sub_type they are
>   – HermanD

You could use a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), although I have heard recently that people frown on the overuse of this pattern. Basically, use the factory to create the actual types you want to get

```
class EventFactory
  def EventFactory.create_event(event_type)
    event_type.constantize.new()
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To me it sounds like you'll need some mojo in the `event#create` action:

```
type = params[:event].delete(:type)

# check that it is an expected value!!!
die unless ['Event', 'SpecialEvent'].include(type)

type.constantize.new(params[:event])
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Rails does not allow you to set Type directly.  Here's what I do...

```
klass_name = 'Foo'
...
klass = Class.const_get(klass_name)
klass.new # Foo.new
```

I believe .constantize is a Rails inflector shortcut.  const_get is a Ruby method on Class and Module.

Comment: This won't work if you're using namespaces for your classes, ie. Class.const_get('Foo::Bar') will result in an error. 'Foo::Bar'.constantize will work though.

Answer (score 0):

Up front I'll agree that STI is often NOT the best way to deal with things.  Polymorphism, yes, but it's often better to use a polymorphic association than STI.

That said, I had a system in which STI was important.  It was a judicial system and things like court cases were remarkably similar across their types and generally shared all their essential attributes.  However, a civil case and a criminal case differed in the elements they managed.  This happened at several levels in the system so abstracted my solution.

https://github.com/arvanasse/sti_factory

Long story short, it uses a factory method to leverage the common approach described above.  As a result, the controller can remain neutral/ignorant of the particular type of STI class that you're creating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rails [safe_constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-safe_constantize) method, which will ensure the object/class actually exists.

For example:

```
def typeify(string)
  string.classify.safe_constantize
end

new_special_event = typeify('special_event').new
```