# Rails 2.3.4: How to filter models sharing same tables based on their own type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Consider the following example code:

```
def Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

def Book < Product
end
```

(I gave up finding a name for this kind of relationship.  I thought Book is a "child model" and Product is the "parent," but that is incorrect.  For example, a Comment model object linked to another Comment model object is what would be a "child-parent" relationship.  If you have a better way to describe the relationship of the models in my code above, you're welcome to write it down here.  Either way, this is not really why I'm here.)

Of course, with the code above, the Book model will share the same database table than Product, "products."  The model type will be saved as a string in the table's "type" column.  So, calling Product.create will insert a row in the table with the type value set to "Product" and using with Book.create will do the same but with the value of "Book."

What puzzles me, however, is calling Book.last will return the last row with the type "Book," as I expect it, but Product.last will return the last row no matter what type, including "Product" and "Book," even though I wish to only get the last "Product."

I tried defined a default_scope in Product which I override in my Book, but that causes more problems than it solves, and messed up my named scopes in Product which are inherited by Book.

Is there a way to make Product.last return the last object of type "Product" and avoid any objects of type "Book"?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: As a side note, the "relationship" between your two sample classes is called inheritance. It's not a relationship like the ":has_one", ":has_many", etc. relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic misunderstanding here seems to be between the concept of "relationships" or "associations" (such as "has_one", "belongs_to", etc.), and the object oriented concept of inheritance.

**Read up on this:** http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html

Based on your example, I think you've got the concept of associations figured out, but you're confusing it with **inheritance**, which isn't the same, and you're not quite understanding here.

When a class inherits from another class (in your example, Book inherits from Product), the "child" class gets all the functionality of the "parent" class, plus any new functionality that it adds on top of that.

Because of that, **all Books are Products, but not all Products are Books**.

The reason Product.last returns the last row in the products table regardless of type, is because all Products (including Books) are products. So, a Book IS a product, therefore if the last Product is a Book, that will be returned.

---

Ok, so the easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do here is to define all types of Products as sub-types of Product, and never use Product.last.

Let's say you're keeping track of Books, CDs, and Cars

class Book < Product
class CD < Product
class Car < Product

This way, when you need to get the newest Book, CD, or Car added to the database, you do Book.last, CD.last, or Car.last. If you just need to know the newest Product of **any** type, you do Product.last.

Comment: I was afraid it might just be that, but I wanted to hear it from someone else first before drawing a conclusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me pretty clear that Product.last should return the last row, since everything is a "Product" in your table. What you want to do is search for the specific type "Product", but as it turns out the table doesn't actually set a type for Product, it just leaves it nil.

So this actually works, I think:

```
Product.find_last_by_type(nil)
```

Can you try it out? I tested on a different table but I think this should work.

Comment: I wrote a migration script to set the default value of type to "Product."  I thought it had to be set anyway, and it is being set in the database table when creating a new Product.  I was hoping for a way to call Product.last without having to specify the type, like I can do with Book.last.  I have the feeling there's just something simple I'm missing...

Comment: Hmm. I don't think you ever really need to explicitly set the type. If your models are created as above, simply calling Product.new(...) or Book.new(...) is enough. In fact even if I try to set the type on the parent, it reverts it to nil. Here's confirmation of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435678/rails-single-table-inheritance-what-is-the-best-way-to-explicitly-set-type

Comment: here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858122/rails-sti-and-the-setting-of-the-type-string

Comment: So my advice would be to switch the type of Products (i.e. Products which are not Books) to null in a migration, and they search as above for nil types.

Comment: All right. I haven't thought of that and I'll surely consider it. Thanks for digging into this! Too bad my user account here is too new to allow me to vote your comment up. ;)

Comment: I suppose the best way to do what I was trying to do would be to have a third separate model, like this:

    `def Sellable < ActiveRecord::Base;
    end;

    def Product < Sellable;
    end;

    def Book < Sellable;
    end;`

But this will be for another day.

Comment: I just tweeted this, but be careful when you go more than one level deep with inheritance using STI. I hit a snag recently with exactly that when I was setting conditions on an association. Rails won't recognize Product in your example above, only the absolute parent, Sellable. There's a post somewhere on it.